# How can I use a Lwt library from Async code?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-lwt

I found this: https://github.com/janestreet/lwt-async

But I don't understand at all where it's supposed to go. Is it a replacement for Lwt that I just have to drop in my folder and link at compile time?

Is there a another way to call Lwt code from a codebase that uses Jane Street's Async?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that it is a clone of `lwt` library that uses async as an engine. AFAIK, it was never officially released.